# Is there any way to upload folders using testcafe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, automated-tests, testcafe

I have to write an e2e test for folder upload by drag-drop functionality in my portal using testcafe. I know there is a method setFilesToUpload() to upload files but is there any method using which we can upload a folder/directory structure?

Comment: can please provide your code for munch understanding.

Answer (score 4):

At present, you cannot specify a folder for the [`setFilesForUpload`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/upload.html#populate-file-upload-input) action.
You need to specify all file paths in the folder.
Here is an example:

`await t
    .setFilesToUpload('#upload-input', [
        'folder1/1.jpg',
        'folder1/2.jpg',
        'folder1/3.jpg'
    ])`

I've created a suggestion regarding your case - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3206. You can track it to be notified of our progress.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).